# Cannot find bind-address in my.conf of MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, nano, mysql-8.0

I have installed MySQL 8.0 on Google Compute Engine instance. I would like to follow [this document](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access) to grant remote access from outside. However, after opening my.conf from /etc/mysql/, there is no line regarding bind-address in the file

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

How can I find bind-address to modify? Thank!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like that the additional configuration are found at the other directives:

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

For ubuntu,most of the settings you are looking for are now found in  "/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf"

I have notified the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access#configure_mysql_server_on_my-server) team internally to update the document.

Instance-dev@ubuntu123:/etc/mysql$  sudo grep -rnw 'bind-address' /etc/mysql

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf:43:bind-address              = 127.0.0.1